# Trying to add an option to a select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

The code below removes all options in my edit form. But after the options are removed I want to add a default option. I've tried the code below, but also .add and .prepend I just can't find the right code for this. What am I doing wrong?

```
$("#editform").find("select").each(function(){
                alert(this.id);
                this.options.length = 0;
                this.append($('<option/>', { value: '', text : 'Selecteer' }));
            });
```

Comment: Replace `this` by `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you checked the console.log, you'd likely see an error that says something like `Uncaught TypeError: this.append is not a function`. Append is a jQuery function, and therefore you need to use the jQuery constructor function. Change `this` to `$(this)`. ie:

```
$("#editform").find("select").each(function(){
   alert(this.id);
   this.options.length = 0;
   $(this).append($('<option/>', { value: '', text : 'Selecteer' }));
});
```

Comment: Is the this.options.length = 0; also incorrect then?

Comment: No. In that case, `this` refers to the object found (in this case, a select element). You're fine using just `this` within the scope of each. If you were to use `$(this)` it would be using jQuery to try and execute an `.options()` method, which does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
append is jquery function:
$("#editform").find("select").each(function(){
            alert(this.id);
            this.options.length = 0;
            $(this).append($('<option/>', { value: '', text : 'Selecteer' }));
        });
```

Comment: A code-only answer will never be as good as an answer with, if not some accompanying text to explain, comments. — [During review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/10297448).

Comment: append is jquery function, when using [this] means using javascript and not jquery, and in this case [this] has no function called append